# 302 from Apache

Tags: c#, apache, httpclient

I have a C# app to log on a website and collects some data. The server (Apache) sometimes sends back the 302 code whereupon the C# application sends a request again to the server with the same URI. The problem is the Apache stops with 'W' status (HttpClient stuck on request).
I would like to know if I send a request with the response.ResponseURI that it would be solve this problem, and why the server sends the code 302 so on erratic way? Someone said me the Apache answers this code (302) when the content of the requested page was not changed. ???

Help me, please?

Comment: HTTP 302 means; "not changed". You can force a refresh by setting the "cache-control" header to "no-cache" on your request.

Comment: isn't the 'not-changed header 304 instead? 302 is a redirect, with a Location header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html . If you have a 302 code response you should redo a request with the URI indicated by the Location: header of the HTTP server response.

This is a temporary redirect.

Redirect are quite common in response to POST requests (to be perfect it should be a 303 redirect...) and it's quite certainly done to redirect you to the home page url for logged in users OR to the login form if you failed your login.